# Youtube is very slow on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, youtube

I have raspberry pi 4 B 4GB model, and i installed ubuntu 64bit. When i watch youtube with 1080p, it lags a lot. I tried many things, I tried splitting memory, using chromium, I set chromium to use gpu but It's still slow and lags a lot. CPU is 100% for all cores, and temperature is really hot.

Edit:I didn't overclocked rpi 4

Comment: Are you aware that The Raspbian version of Chromium has been optimised two ways - first is a media version and second is using video chip processing  see https://blog.vpetkov.net/2019/07/12/netflix-and-spotify-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-latest-default-chromium/ for possible work around stop help the DRM issues.  Note I do not know if this will work in your case or if it is valid software.

Comment: My RasPi4 (4gb) struggles with YouTube as well.  Might be just a limited processing power issue(?).

Comment: Have you changed the amount of RAM available to the GPU? Try to bring it up to at least 128MB.

Comment: yeah, i already tried memory split, but it was still slow

Answer (score 2):

There could be one or more issues going on:

- Your display might not be 1080p capable
- The content you are watching may be out of sync of what the display is capable of.
- Your internet connection may be bad.

Let me know what the issue may be.

Comment: My display is 1920x1080. It is usually used for display for my pc, and i also tried wired connection, i just pulled lan cable from my pc and put it into rpi, i'm sure that i changed connection to wired connection. But nothing is changed

Comment: Hmm, it could be a compatibility issue. Try use another monitor with an HDMI cable, such as a TV.

Comment: I just replaced OS to rasbian X. It plays 1080p at 1920x1080 with 60fps on same display. But the issue isn't ended. because there are some people who want to use ubuntu 64bit.